# CSS positioning relatively to parent's parent across angular components

Tags: css, angular, sass, css-position, positioning

currently I'm working on an image galery and image upload tool. In the image below there is a demonstration of my current and my wanted galery state. The user is able to click on the thumbnails and see the large picture below that current thumbnail row in full size, pushing the next rows relative to the components height.

[image]

---

**images.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-box" *ngFor="let img of images$ | async">
    <img class="mat-elevation-z1" [src]="environment.img + '/images/thmb/' + img.id + '.jpg'" (click)="selected = img">
    <app-image-details *ngIf="selected?.id === img.id" [img]="img"></app-image-details>
  </div>
</div>
```

**images.component.scss**

The *theme-flexfix.scss* fixes all images widths equally, while using flex. `flex-container-wrap-items()` makes the container flex and flex-wrap. The .image-box items are flex: 1.

```
@import 'src/theme-flexfix.scss';

.container {
  @include flex-container-wrap-items(128px);
}

.container > .image-box {
  @include flex-wrap-fix(128px);
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* position: relative; */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

**image-details.component.html**

```html
<img [src]="environment.img + '/images/' + img.id + '.jpg'">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

**image-details.component.scss**

```
:host {
  /* position: absolute */
  /* left: 0 */
}
```

---

Tried the commented styles in resulting in what I want, but not pushing the other content. I think there is an easy solution, but for now I can't get it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to replicate Google image search.

**I would go about it like this:**

1. When image is clicked, calculate how many images in a row you are displaying.
2. Inject DIV with larger version of the image after the **last image** in the row.

The idea is to always inject DIV after the end of current row.

This way, your DIV will not be absolutely positioned, but instead will flow with HTML and no absolute positioning hacking is required.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out your solution. Yeah it's similar to google images. A css-only version seems to be more code saving and maybe more elegant to me. If I do as you suggest: The preview items are flex, am I either able to add a non-flex position relative item between flex items or to add a flex: 0 0 100%?

Comment: Make it flex as well, just make it fill the space horizontally. In my view, that preview box is no different from all other images, it's just larger and fills the entire row. Depends how you define cleanness. If it's just a matter of adding the element in semantically correct place in HTML and barely any additional CSS is required, that sounds to me "clean". If you need absolute positioning, in most cases it's not "clean".

Comment: Add some code to your answer. Make a stackblitz or something to actually demonstrate your ideas.

Comment: @zze If I was to add code, it would be a lot of it, and it would be confusing to all but the OP. I would rather stay with an algorithm that I will leave for the future "geeks :)" implement in whatever framework they use.